# Push message causes crash when app is not running

Tags: codenameone

I have  google GCM implemented as native and works fine when the app is actively running on the foreground. However, if the app is not running after some long idle time, when a push message comes in, though it is detected, causes a crash. I dont have a class PushReceiver.java so this must be injected by CN1. Here is the stack trace:

```
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026): java.io.EOFException
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:99)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:178)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:173)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:169)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.getPendingPush(AndroidImplementation.java:381)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at com.rixma.mobile.PushReceiver.handleMessage(PushReceiver.java:162)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at com.rixma.mobile.PushReceiver.onReceive(PushReceiver.java:62)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3011)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:177)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
02-14 22:50:14.796: W/System.err(21026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 22:50:14.806: W/System.err(21026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-14 22:50:14.806: W/System.err(21026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
02-14 22:50:14.806: W/System.err(21026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
02-14 22:50:14.806: D/AndroidRuntime(21026): Shutting down VM
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026): Process: com.rixma.mobile, PID: 21026
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.rixma.mobile.PushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3018)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:177)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at com.rixma.mobile.PushReceiver.handleMessage(PushReceiver.java:163)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at com.rixma.mobile.PushReceiver.onReceive(PushReceiver.java:62)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3011)
02-14 22:50:14.806: E/AndroidRuntime(21026):    ... 9 more
```

Please advice how to work around this as it seems i do not have any control over the crashing code, it seems to be happening in CN1 code. I am supposed to use such push notifications to wake up a 'dead' app, as long as it was not forcefully stopped by user.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add your code but as long as your receiving process has something to do with the activities you will have problems when the app is not in foreground because they are dead.
You should handle all the process in a background service.

Answer (score 0):

The push support that is builtin to [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) assumes that you are using the Codename One push. The main reason is the fragmentation of the push implementations across devices, Android & iOS are radically different here.